# Selenium - test iframe inside shadow dom

Tags: angular, selenium, iframe, protractor, shadow-dom

I have an angular app with enabled ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom, inside which there is an iframe.
When I'm trying to write protractor test I'm getting an error:

```
Failed: unknown error: no element reference returned by script
```

While I'm able to actually get web element, I can't perform any actions with it.

```
const root = element(by.css('app-root')).getWebElement();
    browser.driver
      .executeScript('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', root)
      .then((shadowRoot: WebElement) => {
        browser.switchTo()
          .frame(shadowRoot.findElement(by.css('iframe')))
          .then(()=>{
            element(by.css('.app-block')).getWebElement().then(el=>{
              console.log("EL:",el); //logs element
              browser.actions().mouseMove(el).perform(); //throws error
            });
          });
      });
```

Is there a way to properly switch to iframe nested in shadow dom?

Comment: what kind of error though?

Comment: "Failed: unknown error: no element reference returned by script".
But I know that it has found the element, since it also logs "more than one element found for locator By(css selector, .app-block) - the first result will be used"

Comment: is this a public webpage you're trying to automate? I never worked with `shadow elements`, curious what's the deal about them. And maybe could help you out

Comment: Wild stab; ``browser.actions().mouseMove()`` is a **global** function, while the parameter you give it ``(el)`` is a reference to an element in a shadowRoot. So you have to find out **if** ``mouseMove()`` can access shadow content at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin [query-selector-shadow-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-selector-shadow-dom). On your conf.js file add this

```
plugins: [{
    package: 'query-selector-shadow-dom/plugins/protractor'
}],
```

Then switch now to iframe by using the shadow `by.shadowDomCss`.